# how to create 1 c# sdk of multiple swagger models - Amazon SP API

Tags: c#, sdk, swagger-codegen, amazonsellercentral

Below document for selling partner API gives example to generate sdk client for sellersapi for java, but it does not give any example for csharp. I have managed to create for cSharp for 1 and multiple APIs(for example Feeds, Orders, Tokens, Fullfilmentoutbound). But the issue I'm having is Money class existed in Orders and Fulfillmentoutbound, so the one with fulfillmentoutbound got overwritten on Orders Money class

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#swagger-codegen-cli.jar

The command I used was below

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/orders-api-model/ordersV0.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/feeds-api-model/feeds_2020-09-04.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/reports-api-model/reports_2021-06-30.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/tokens-api-model/tokens_2021-03-01.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/fulfillment-outbound-api-model/fulfillmentOutbound_2020-07-01.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/merchant-fulfillment-api-model/merchantFulfillmentV0.json --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
```

Anyones knows what I can do so that it does not overwrite, or currently its adding all model classes for all api endpoints in same folder, may be having them all created in separate folder for their endpoint would work

Answer (score 0):

So I have been able to do this with below commands, here we are creating files under their API and Models folder

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/orders-api-model/ordersV0.json --api-package Api.Orders --model-package Models.Orders --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/feeds-api-model/feeds_2020-09-04.json --api-package Api.Feeds --model-package Models.Feeds --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/reports-api-model/reports_2021-06-30.json --api-package Api.Reports --model-package Models.Reports --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/tokens-api-model/tokens_2021-03-01.json --api-package Api.Tokens --model-package Models.Tokens --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/fulfillment-outbound-api-model/fulfillmentOutbound_2020-07-01.json --api-package Api.FulFillmentOutBound --model-package Models.FulFillmentOutBound --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.13.jar generate -l csharp -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/merchant-fulfillment-api-model/merchantFulfillmentV0.json --api-package Api.MerchantFulFillment --model-package Models.MerchantFulFillment --additional-properties -DmodelTests=false -DapiTests=false -DpackageName='AmazonSPAPI.Sdk'
```

Comment: I followed https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/generate-a-c-sharp-sdk-with-lwa-token-generation-and-authentication but it creates a separate one for each model. I ran your command(s) and it generated my solution. However how do I call the API making sure I set the correct AWS/LWA credentials?